# Using dropdown parameters in SSRS report

Tags: reporting-services, ssrs-2008

I can see the text box for my data set that having the

"select col1 from table name " as query. I want to populate dropdown instead of text box. I  have created the parameter for it .
what to do?

Answer (score 25, accepted):

In short

1. Right click the parameter
2. Select "Available Values" section
3. Click the "Get values from a query"
   option
4. Select the appropriate dataset and
   fields

Comment: Do you happen to know how I display the text instead of the value from the dropdown on the report?  I have guid and Description but if I add the parameter I get the guid on the report. Clearly I want to show the Description of the selected item but can't work out how.

Comment: Never mind. I got there. Added a text box with this expression:  =First(Fields!Text.Value, "DateDropDown")

Answer (score 7):

My solution:

1. Right click the parameter under the "**Report Data**" and select "**Parameter Properties**"
2. Select "**Available Values**" section
3. Click the "**Get values from a query**" option

4a. Select the appropriate **query** to use

4b. Select the **Value** that you want the main query to use to generate the data

4c. Select the **Label** that will show in the drop down box that the User sees and selects a option from

Comment: This answered was perfect, I could not figure out how to find the "Parameter Properties" and this gave exact directions.

Answer (score 5):

This following articles cover exactly what you need to know about setting report parameters in SSRS:

- MSDN: [Adding Parameters to Create a List of Available Values (SSRS)](http://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/aa337400.aspx)
- [Building Reports in SQL Server](http://en.csharp-online.net/Building_Reports_in_SQL_Server_2005%E2%80%94Setting_Report_Parameters_with_Stored_Procedures)

Comment: This is not working for me, intention is this , is any setting to view the dropdown instead of text box? I have VS 2008, sql server 2008 R2

Comment: Did you follow the steps in the MSDN article?  In particular, go to the section titled "To populate the report parameter with a list of available values".  Read that section.  It has step by step instructions that will result in a dropdown instead of a textbox.

Answer (score 2):

follow these steps
1.In the Report Data pane, expand the Parameters node and right-click on the parameter, then click Parameter Properties.

2.In Prompt, type Select :.

3.In Data type, select datatype.

4.Click Available Values.

5.Select the Get values from a query option.

6.select value field and Label field

7.In default values select Get values from a query option.
8.From the Dataset drop-down list, select BusinessPersons.

9.From the Value field drop-down list, select BusinessEntityID.

10.Click OK.

Answer (score 2):

If you already deployed a previous version of your report, for some reason this kind of parameter change doesn't get picked up when you redeploy.  Try deleting the report using Report Manager, then redeploy.