# Is it possible to put a drop down list inside a report?

Tags: drop-down-menu, reporting-services

I'm hoping someone might be able to help me. I'm looking at using SSRS to pre-populate fields, and I'd like to have a dropdown list which our staff can select from, when we have them fill out this form online. Is it possible to have a drop down list in one of the tables? Or is it not possible?

I hope this makes sense.

Comment: [Possible duplicate](http://stackoverflow.com/questions/4851800/using-dropdown-parameters-in-ssrs-report)

Answer (score 0, accepted):

First supposing what you mean by *pre-populate fields* is let user to insert data into your database tables using some form then show this data in a report.

Reporting Services is not designed to insert or alter data anyway. Instead it is used commonly for reporting purposes, to show data using charts and controls allowing limited user interaction.

If supposition is wrong and you want to add a drop-down list to filter your data or specify presentation conditions you can use a `parameter`. Go through this [technet](https://technet.microsoft.com/en-us/library/aa337432(v=sql.105).aspx) tutorial where adding and setting for a report parameter is explained.

[image]

It is possible to add custom report items to your report, go to [this](https://technet.microsoft.com/en-us/library/ms345231(v=sql.110).aspx) documentation and check this sample in [codeplex](http://msftrsprodsamples.codeplex.com/).